# Fuera de rango - Tres en rayas

Tags: java

Buenas compañeros tengo este problema al rellenar la posición elegida por la máquina para insertar una forma en la matriz 3x3, me sale un error fuera de rango y no veo por qué... controlo que el número aleatorio para la jugada de la maquina sea entre 1 y 3 y luego como se ve en el código restar uno e insertarlo en la matriz, también he intentado hacer el ramdon para que dé los números 0, 1 y 2 y así no tener que restar al insertarlos en la matriz. Adjunto el código.

```
do {

  posXm = (int)(Math.random()*3+1);
  posYm = (int)(Math.random()*3+1);

  //Devuelve Verdadero o Falso si la posición indicada esta disponible
  insertado = tablero.comprobarHueco((posX-1), (posY-1)); 

} while (insertado); 

//Aquí se inserta la marca "O" en las posiciones indicadas
tablero.rellenarHueco((posXm-1), (posYm-1), "O");
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo!

**EDIT**

Os dejo los métodos comprobarHueco y rellenarHueco

```
 public void rellenarHueco(int posX, int posY, String forma){

        this.tabla[posX][posY] = forma;
    }

    
    public boolean comprobarHueco(int posX, int posY){

        if (this.tabla[posX][posY].equals(".")){
            
            return true;
        }
        else{

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como define tablero.comprobarHueco?

Comment: Buenas Duston, en el método comprobarHueco únicamente compruebo si en la posición X e Y de la matriz creada existe un "." que es el elemento con el que inicialice la matriz, en caso de ser así hace un return true. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en el metodo rellenarHuecos, ya que tus Variables son posXm, y posYm, y tu en `insertado = tablero.comprobarHueco((posX-1), (posY-1));`  le quitas la m a las variables

Comment: Buenas Juan Alberto la cosa es que el método rellenarHueco es muy simple, solo rellena la matriz en las posiciones indicadas. En el método comprobarHueco compruebo si la posición indicada esta libre, es decir, no tiene el valor "."

Comment: ok espera lo reviso y te digo

Comment: Porque tienes el this?

Comment: Con el “this.“ hago referencia a qué estoy trabajando sobre un elemento propio de clase.

Comment: Y  el string forma que contiene

Comment: String forma contiene la marca que va a colocar cada jugador, X o O.

Comment: en la parte de  `insertado = tablero.comprobarHueco((posX-1), (posY-1));` Las  variables PosX y PosY, no deberian ser PosXm y PosYm

Comment: Ostras, cierto Juan Alberto, problema solucionado. Muchísimas gracias por el apoyo 

Comment: podrias marcar la respuesta correcta?, eso me ayudaria  muchisimo

Comment: Por supuesto!!!

Comment: oh! muchas gracias!